# Angular JS application CPU usage is more when idle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope, angularjs-material

I have noticed my angular js application is taking more CPU usage about 45% when it is idle mode. We have built much complex application using angular js V1.6.0, angular material V1.1.5 and d3js V4 as we can see below

Earlier I have worked on the watcher count issues which was causing site to went into not responding mode. There were many watchers based on the no of cards increased in the view because of two way binding. I have worked it out to remove the two way data bindings in some places and load the data which is in only in view port. These approached helped me to bring down the watcher count for the below data in view is as show in the image.

Also many digest cycles were running per millisecond, I could able to fix all of them by triggering digest cycles when needed when user perform some actions or any data updates. I have removed some native angular services for example $timeout service which always trigger digest instead used setTimeout and cleared timeouts.

Now digest cycles when the site is not used is 0 per one ms (please see attached below image).

[image]

Web interface:
[image]

CPU Usage:
[image]

Please explain where I need to look into stuff to bring down the CPU usage percentage.

I am happy to provide some more details if required. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'd start by hitting F12 in chrome and take a look at profiling a few idle minutes

Comment: Sure @birdspider.

Comment: @birdspider Thank you so much for your help. I could be able to identify the issue and I fixed it. So I assume I need to do same while page loading which is also hitting higher CPU percentages

Comment: Use of `$timeout` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. Look into ways of refactoring the code to avoid them.

Comment: @georgeawg Yes you are right regarding $timeout. I have already removed it every where. We have a bower package for d3 js. So we can directly use d3 global object to do the stuff.

Comment: The right way to incorporate D3 with Angular is to use custom directives. Read [How to Combine D3 with AngularJS](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/05/31/how-to-combine-d3-with-angularjs/).

Comment: That's great. I have not used directives but components as I am using angularjs 1.6.2 version.